# can't move button in view controller in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I have created a new view controller in Xcode and added a button . I am trying to add constraints to it to move it to top left hand corner of screen , but all the constraints seem to be disabled.

Also when I am trying to add a second button to the view controller , it replaces the first one rather than adding a second one. [image]

Control and Dragging the button shows the following menu, instead of the adding constraint menu
[image]

Can you point me towards where I am going wrong ?

PS: I am new to using Xcode, so kindly let me know if I need to provide any further details to make it easier for you guys to understand the issue.

Comment: I think the selection that you have there is of View Controller [Play Sounds View Controller]. Try clicking the Button and see if the constraints appear?

Comment: Well it seems that the constraints aren't even added. If you do it correctly, the constraints should appear as a constraint on the button's superview.

Comment: Can you share sample project? @misguided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks for your inputs . I found the issue , the button wasn't on any view , hence when I was trying to control drag i was getting those options. I deleted the button , added a view and then added a button . All good now.

Comment: Glad you found the answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to put button wherever you want and then press button Resolved auto layout issues (Second from the last) at the bottom right corner and select add missing constraints.

And second you can manually add constraint to this button as
 To do 
You need to Control + drag from button to superview for leading space, trailing space, bottom layout and top layout constraints.

Comment: Hi mate updated the screenshot , i have tried what you said already , but it doesn't show any option to add constraint